# Navigating to a web page and downloading a report using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Could you please let me know how to improve the following script to actually click on the export button.

The following script goes to the report's page but does not click on the export button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("<Path to Chrome profile>") #Path to your chrome profile

url = '<URL of the report>'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/tools/selenium/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)

exportButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_2o"]')

clickexport = exportButton.click()
```

How would you make the script actually click on the export button?

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try with xpath, example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="export_button"]').click()
```

Comment: Still not click. I added the current script including the xpath in the question. Would you correct anything in the script?

Comment: i'ts strange... please update the question with a sample of the html document that you're tring to read

Answer (score 0):

Selenium isn't designed for this.  Do you actually care about using Selenium and the browser, or do you just want the file?  If the latter, use `requests`.  You can use the browser network inspector, right click->"copy as curl" to get all the headers and cookies you need.

Comment: It's a report from Ads Manager (Facebook) where you have to click 3 buttons to get the report... Is it possible to use requests and "copy as curl" to download it? If so, Could you please share a step by step of how you would do that? Thank you!

Comment: Navigate to page.  Right click anywhere-> inspect.  Select network tab of inspector.  Click button.  Find the request that corresponds to the request, and right-click-> Copy-> Copy as CuRL.  Paste that into your editor.  You'll see all the headers and cookies that you need to make the request.  Change these to python dicts for headers, and then run basically `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`.

Comment: Copy as CuRl cmd or bash? The request calls other requests. So shall I copy all the following requests too on only the first one that runs when I click to download the report? How do you convert the request to a python duct? What would be the script that you would use to run the request in python? Thank you?

Comment: You want the one that corresponds to the data that you actually want.  I tend to look at the size of the output, but you can also look at the response itself in the inspector.

Comment: How would you request the curl command? Please find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398377/downloading-an-ads-manager-report-using-python